# Error with Server 2012 Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have just recently installed Server 2012 on my server. I installed ADDS, set it up with "xesonnetworks.com" forest. Now, I cannot add any computer or access the administrative center to the domain. When I try open ADAC it says "No domain could be found running", and when I try to add a Windows 8 server to the domain, it says that the domain controller couldn't be contacted. Does anyone know why?/

Thanks.

Comment: No, did I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause of this is that your client computer can't find the required records in DNS, and you didn't say you set it up, so I expect that might be the problem.

If you are doing this, your DC(s) must be the authoritative nameservers for your domain when your clients query them.  This is because they will be looking for records like `IN SRV _msdcs.xesonnetworks.com`, which are automatically added to DNS by your DC when setting it up.  Generally when you set up a DC it will also install the DNS service for this reason.

The easiest way to effect this is to use the DCs as your nameservers for your clients (though doing so requires that you leave recursion enabled on them).  You can also set up other DNS servers which have zone data pointing to your DCs as the authoritative nameservers for your domain, and use those as the recursive resolvers for your clients, though that is slightly more complicated.

If for some reason the records couldn't be created during `dcpromo` you would have got a bunch of warnings.  If you ignored them and you just created the domain, the easiest thing to do is probably to start over.

It goes without saying that you should be able to ping the DC from the clients without issue.

Comment: I can ping "xesonnetworks.com" and access the website that is hosted.

Comment: Yes, that is fine.  You should check for the AD records in the DNS server.  Also you really, really, really shouldn't host websites (especially public ones!) on DCs.

Comment: Now that you say that, I might put the DC on my second server.

Comment: Not a bad plan.  If you make sure the clients can get the SRV records AD set up, by one means or another, the error will go away.